# Why my MTD driver becomes a normal file?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, driver, embedded-linux, kernel-module

I am using phram and ramoops to store the latest system log in a reserved memory, so that once my machine crashed I could dump the panic log after reboot. MTD driver `phram` and module `ramoops` are used to automatically record the system log to memory:

```
/# insmod /lib/modules/phram.ko phram=phram-oops,<addr>,<len>    
/# ls -l /dev/mtdchar/param-oops
crw-r--r--    1 root     root       90,  24 Jul 20 16:34 phram-oops
```

It worked well until recently I reused this driver to also backup the boot loader log - during the boot, phram-oops backs up the u-boot log to one reserved memory area; and after Linux shell is up, dump the u-boot log, clear phram-oops by `dd if=/dev/zero bs=65536 count=1 of=/dev/mtdchar/param-oops`, rmmod phram and insmod phram with a new memory area for panic log. Then dumping the system logs of last boot. Until this step, `/dev/mtdchar/phram-oops` still works fine:

```
/# ls -l /dev/mtdchar/phram-oops
crw-r--r--    1 root     root       90,  24 Jul 20 16:34 /dev/mtdchar/phram-oops
```

However, after running `dd if=/dev/zero bs=65536 count=1 of=/dev/mtdchar/phram-oops” again to clear the memory, driver`/dev/mtdchar/phram-oops` becomes a file!!!

```
/# ls -l /dev/mtdchar/phram-oops
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root         65536 Jul 20 16:34 /dev/mtdchar/phram-oops
```

And as a result the previous logs remains in the memory and could not be cleared. Any idea about how a driver turns to a file? And how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

It seems this problem was caused by hotplug - it requires some delay after `rmmod phram` and before `insmod phram` with a new address. Otherwise, the device driver is very likely not correctly loaded and as a result the `dd` command could create it as a normal file.

Comment: what if I'm not seeing a /dev/mtdchar/phram-oops ?